# How to create a project in same window of Android Studio?

Tags: android, window, android-studio

When I try to create a new project in Android Studio,it always open in New Window only.I also changed setting in General in Preferences option.But still the issue persists,how can I fix it.Kindly help me with your guidance.Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> Please visit the below mentioned link:

[Android Studio - How to open multiple project in single window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646114/android-studio-how-to-open-multiple-project-in-single-window)

> Hope this will help you.