# How to import external project folder in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This question might look very silly to many. But i could not get answer from anywhere in google. I downloaded a eclipse project and tried to import it in Android Studio. The downloaded zip file has two folder like this.[image: downloaded zip file]

Now how do i import them as a single project? Help me

This the project i like to import
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Game_Card/Download_Free_code_Ace_It.htm

Comment: Use "Import project" or "Open existing project", also you can follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response. And ya imported the folder CardGame. My problem is now how do i include the CardGameServer in that imported(CardGame) project

Comment: Well, you are trying to import multiple projects in AndroidStudio and following this answer... this is not possible [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16646203/4385913)

Comment: Can you help me importing this project. http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Game_Card/Download_Free_code_Ace_It.htm

Comment: Did you try only open Ace it Master folder? or just with Shift select the CardGame and CardGameServer?

Comment: I tried opening Ace it master folder but it says its not a valid project since it does not have manifest file. When i tried Cardgame it worked perfectly. But the game not functioning properly

Answer (score 0):

Just open Android Studio > Import Non-Android Studio Projects > Select your ADT project folder.

It creates a new AS-version of your project, and reports items that need your manual verification.

Comment: Sorry i dont see an option "Import Non-Android studio Projects". And this is the project i like to import. http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Game_Card/Download_Free_code_Ace_It.htm. Can u Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Android Studio > Import Project > Choose the Card Game folder (not the master folder) > Click next > check all boxes Click finish

Comment: it seems not, it gives a nullpoiter exception eventually , but thats another question by itself