# Android Studio Project Import takes to new Tab

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am new to `Android Studio`. Before that, I was developing Android apps using `Eclipse`. Now I am going to start development using `Android Studio`. But I am facing an issue. As in Eclipse, if we import more than one projects, they all stay in the same `workspace`. But in `Android Studio`, if a project is opened, and when I try to `import/open` another project, it launches the new window for that project. I want to keep all projects in the same window as Eclipse does. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646114/android-studio-how-to-open-multiple-project-in-single-window

Comment: I haven't found any help from that link. It is not duplicate.