# Importing a maven project on Github into Android Studio as dependency

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I am trying to work on an android app using Android Studio and I want to use the [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) github project in my app. This github project appears to be related to Maven (Disclosure: I've never used Maven before).

I want to be able to reference its classes in my Android Studio project.
I tried to create a new module, but that it creates its own directory structure. I want to just import the existing file structure of this github project (so I don't change anything related to it).

Can anyone tell what is the recommended way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - How to open multiple project in single window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646114/android-studio-how-to-open-multiple-project-in-single-window)

Answer (score 0):

if this library can be found in maven central search, you can just go to

- file
- project structure
- while selected in the left "app" under modules 
  go to Dependecies tab
- click + button on the right and choose library dependency and search for           your lib.(there is another sliding menu lib then yours i think)
- use it in your code

otherwise:

if you want to add the library you posted, download it and go to

- file
- project structure
- click + button (top left corner this time)
- in the new window select "import gradle project " choose the folder of your lib (if it will not do this, choose the library folder inside it(idk this lib)).  i think it will import your lib
- then go to dependencies tab
- click + button and choose add module dependency this time choose your lib and your done
- use it in your code

have fun